# How to set the maths font in Beamer when using XeLaTeX?

Tags: beamer, xetex, fontspec, mathdesign

I am using XeLaTeX with fontspec and mathdesign to set the maths font separately. This works fine in `memoir`, for example, but Beamer overrides my maths font settings and uses the main font as a maths font.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Minimum working example}
\begin{itemize}
    \item normal text set in Liberation Serif and maths \textbf{also,} instead of Adobe Utopia as intended
        \[v_x(t) := \lim\limits_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} =: \frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t}\]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output, all set in the main font:

[image]

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the command that worked is `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

Comment: If you are using xetex you probably should be using `unicode-math` for changing the math font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you found out yourself, `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` is needed
to be able to use opentype fonts with beamer.

However, I want to add that you probably should use `unicode-math` together with xelatex to change the math-fonts.

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
% check name of font for your system, this works on Ubuntu
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Unicode-Examples}
  Some unicode in formulas:
  \begin{equation}
    α² + β² = γ²
  \end{equation}
  And a fraction: ½.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

For some reason the comments containing the answer have disappeared, but I hope it is not impolite to answer my own question on the basis of those comments.

The solution is to use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` in the preamble.

The minimum working example is now:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% SOLUTION
%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Minimum working example}
\begin{itemize}
    \item normal text set in Liberation Serif and maths \textbf{also,} instead of Adobe Utopia as intended
        \[v_x(t) := \lim\limits_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} =: \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Producing
[image]

(having corrected the physics mistake above as well).

Comment: Please provide a [`MWE`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).